# Raspberry pi 400 won't run 4k at 60hz

Tags: hdmi

I've added hdmi_enable_4kp60=1 to the config file, I'm using the official hdmi cable and power adapter and I've tested it on a 4k monitor and a tv.
Yet the maximum refresh rate is still 30hz in the display settings.
here's the full config file

```
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
over_voltage=6
arm_freq=2000

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

# Automatically load overlays for detected cameras
camera_auto_detect=1

# Automatically load overlays for detected DSI displays
display_auto_detect=1

# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2


# Run in 64-bit mode
arm_64bit=1

# Disable compensation for displays with overscan
disable_overscan=1

[cm4]
# Enable host mode on the 2711 built-in XHCI USB controller.
# This line should be removed if the legacy DWC2 controller is required
# (e.g. for USB device mode) or if USB support is not required.
otg_mode=1

[all]



[pi4]
# Run as fast as firmware / board allows
arm_boost=1
hdmi_enable_4kp60=1
```

Comment: Have you selected a 60hz resolution in 'Screen Configuration'? https://medium.com/@monofuel34089/running-your-raspberry-pi-4-at-4k60hz-78010a26e98d

Comment: @CoderMike 30hz is the maximum option available